# Angular 2, Cant able to access a variable in one Component from another Component

Tags: angular, angular2-components

Sorry if this is a duplicated question, I have searched solution throughout the Web can't able to find any so am posting it, Am trying to access a variable from one component inside another component

**What I have Tried**

I have created a model of object type and have set the value inside a component A method, and tried to access that model object from component B so that I can set the value for the Component B Elements, but getting object as undefined

**Problem**

Component A is loaded first in browser, where it contains a table on click of the table row am getting the row data as object and setting that object to a Model which contains a similar structure object and I can able to get the object value in Component, whereas I tried to call the model from a Component B so that I can access the object value. but am getting the object value as undefined this is due to the Component B is a Modal which is Called inside the Component A Template.

**Component A**

```
 public rowSelected:boolean = true;
 constructor(public users : User ) {}
  getRowData(rowIndex: number, rowData: any): void { 
        this.rowSelected = $(rowIndex).hasClass('selected');
        console.log(rowData);
        this.users= rowData.FirstName;
        console.log(this.users); // can able to get the object value
    }
```

**Component A Template**

```
<div bsModal #editUserModal="bs-modal" class="modal fade" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button class="close" aria-label="Close" type="button" (click)="editUserModal.hide()">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
                <h5 class="modal-title"><b>Edit User</b></h5>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <componenetB #edituserDiv></componenetB>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm  confirm-btn gap0" type="button" (click)="edituserDiv.EditUserSubmit()">Submit</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm gap-left10 gap0" type="button" (click)="editUserModal.hide()">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Model**

```
export class User {
    UserName: any
    Password: any
    FirstName: any
    MiddleName: any
    LastName: any
    Status: any
    Locked: any
    Active: any
    CreatedOn: any
    LastModified: any

}
```

**Component B**

```
export class Component B   { 

    constructor(public userz : User) {     
console.log(this.userz) // Object Value is Undefined
    }

}
```

Please help me to resolve this issue, thanks in advance

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt3.html

Comment: @DeblatonJean-Philippe can you please point out what is wrong ?..

Comment: @DeblatonJean-Philippe actually am setting the data on click of the row, so initially the component B gets undefined value using @input()

Comment: Without @Input() and @Output you cant pass data between components

Comment: am getting console Error as Cannot read property 'emit' of undefined, any idea

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `@Input` when you want to [**pass data from parent to child**](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#parent-to-child). Here I assume `users` is an array. If not, adjust the type accordingly.

So in your parent template:

```
<componenetB [users]="users"></componenetB>
```

From your child (component B), do not inject `User` in constructor. Use `@Input` instead:

```
export class Component B   { 
    @Input users: User[];

    constructor() { }
}
```

So that you do not get undefined error if the `users` is actually set later, just instantiate the `users` in your parent, so that it won't be undefined, while it waits for values to be set:

```
users: User[] = [];
```

Here is a demo, which simulates the values of `users` are set at a later point. Just click the button and the values will appear in child, values that are set in the parent.

### [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/rnpqyxGgyjaOQtCgXe02?p=preview)

Comment: but am setting the data inside a method from Component A

Comment: Well that is what it is doing. Look closely at plunker. When you click the button in parent, `setUsers` is fired, which sets the values, and then they are shown in child.

Comment: thanks a lot buddy, your answer gave me a good idea to complete my work

Comment: No problem, glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

I can't see the binding. May be you are missing something like 
    `<hero-detail [hero]="selectedHero"></hero-detail>`

Comment: I have tried that also, am setting the value while on click of the table row so my component B gets undefined data, have any idea on this

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand your question. If this answers you question remember to mark it as answer.

If you have a component (A - parent) which has child component (B - child), then you can use Input/Output decorators to communicate between them.

Child component has event property userSelected, it will fire event when **emit(value?: T): void** method will be called. Parent component will receive event here - **(userSelected)="onUserSelect($event)** where *$event* contains value passed to emit method. So it can be used in parent component

> More detailed description here: http://learnangular2.com/outputs/

Parent:

```
@Component({
   selector: 'component-a',
   template:'<component-b (userSelected)="onUserSelect($event)"></component-b>'
})
export class AComponent{
    selectedUser: User;
    onUserSelect(user: User){
       this.selectedUser = user;
    }
}
```

Child:

```
@Component({
   selector: 'component-b'
})
export class BComponent {
   @Output() userSelected: EventEmitter<User>;

   rowClicked(user: User): void {
       this.userSelected.emit(user);
   }
}
```

**UPDATE - Input version**

> According to Component A template, component B is child of component A

Further I go into your implementation, I get the feeling that whole logic is weird.
As I understand, you have a table of users in Component A, then when a row is selected modal window pops up (component B) where you manipulate user details.
So template for component A should look like this (simplified version):

```
<div class="modal-body">
   <componenetB [selectedUser]="selectedUser"></componenetB>
</div>
```

Then for B component define input variable with same name as used in A template

```
@Component({
   selector: 'component-b'
})
export class BComponent {
   @Input() selectedUser: User;

   //Further your logic using selectedUser variable
   //If need to return modified selectedUser to A component, use Output
}
```

Well it seems that you miss code logic to select user. I guess you should have something similar to this, that is just an example. You should pass whole object to component B.

```
<table>
   <tr*ngFor="let user of users">
      <td (onClick)="openBModal(user)">{{user.UserName}}</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

To give more precise answer please provide plunker with your example, with this little information is hard to understand what are you going to achieve

Comment: @MBalajivaishnav logic stays the same, just other way around. This is an example for your problem. Just switch components and you get your desired solution.

Comment: I understand that but if I switch the logic vice versa I can't able to get the desired output, actually output decorator used to pass data from child to parent component, but am trying parent to child, I don't think so output will help me instead I need to opt for input decorator

Answer (score 0):

Component A

```
import {Component,EventEmitter} from "@angular/core";
import {User} from "User.Model";

@Component({
   selector: 'component-A',
   outputs :["selectedUser"],
   templateUrl:''
})

export class AppComponent{
 selectedUser : new EventEmitter<User>;
 public rowSelected:boolean = true;
 constructor(public users : User ) {}
 getRowData(rowIndex: number, rowData: any): void { 
        this.rowSelected = $(rowIndex).hasClass('selected');
        console.log(rowData);
        this.users= rowData.FirstName;
        this.selectedUser.emit(this.users);
    }
}
```

Component B Html

`<component-a (selectedUser)="PrintUserInfo($event)"></component-a>`

Component B.ts

```
// skipping some code
export class BComponent{
     PrintUserInfo(user :User): void {
       console.log("Name :" + user.Name);
   }
}
```

Comment: can you plz check your code I think it's wrong, I need to emit data from component A to component B

Comment: And it is Working Fine

Comment: am getting console Error as Cannot read property 'emit' of undefined

Comment: `selectedUser : new EventEmitter<User>;` have you written this line inside your class ?

Comment: I think you are using a older version of Angular 2 ?.. because output is a separate decorator and not used with in the component decorator

Comment: Why do I need to use Component A inside my Component B ? am already using component B inside component A