# Access a variable from another Component (Ionic/Cordova/Angular)

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic3

I'm trying to access a variable from another component in order to check if the user is logged in or not.

The application does the follow:

If user is loggedin (function in login.ts) user will not be null anymore therefor [disabled]=!user wont be true anymore and the first year field will be activated.

I Implemented the following stackoverflow solution but that did not work:
[Angular 2, Cant able to access a variable in one Component from another Component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43347526/angular-2-cant-able-to-access-a-variable-in-one-component-from-another-componen)

Here is my code that is related to this problem:

```
          ` https://plnkr.co/edit/xzHazahrSHErJa9K0ceb?p=preview `
```

Thank you!

Comment: Can you post the code rather than dead link?

Comment: use a `Provider` instead to share data.

Comment: @ Astra Bear link is not dead. what do you mean by use a Provider?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is the sample code where we will pass data from home page to about page on navigation. Home page will have a button **Go to about page**, on clicking that button, your name will be passed to about page through navParams and it will be displayed in About page. You can also find the working version [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic3-passdata-to-different-page-example)

**home.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import {appService} from '../../providers/app.service';
import {AboutPage} from '../../pages/about/about';
@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
  aboutPage : any;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public appService : appService) {
    this.aboutPage=AboutPage;
  }

  goToAbout(){
    this.navCtrl.push(this.aboutPage, {
            userData: "Ajay kumar singh"
        });
  }

}
```

In Home page, use [navParams](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavParams/) to receive the values you sent from sign up page.

```
userData : any;
constructor(public navParams: NavParams){
   this.userData= navParams.data.userData;
}
```

**home.html**

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Home</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  <h2>Welcome to Ionic!</h2>
  <p>
    This starter project comes with simple tabs-based layout for apps
    that are going to primarily use a Tabbed UI.
  </p>
  <p>
    Take a look at the <code>pages/</code> directory to add or change tabs,
    update any existing page or create new pages. {{appService.service}}
  </p>

  <button ion-button (click)="goToAbout()">Go to About Page</button>
</ion-content>
```

**about.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-about',
  templateUrl: 'about.html'
})
export class AboutPage {
  userData : any;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, navParams : NavParams) {
    this.userData= navParams.data.userData;
  }

}
```

**about.html**

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>
      About
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  {{userData}}
</ion-content>
```

Comment: I will try that now, any reason why you added appService as Injectable? I do not see you using it anywhere.

Comment: Ignore appService, it's added for another sample and it's not need for your requirement.

Comment: What you are doing here is clicking on the button, once clicked going to another page while sending the parameters along with it. But what I actually wants: LogIn page > [Once loggedIn it sends you to] > LoggedIn page so now I have in HomePage a form that checks whether the user is logged in or not. that's what I need. So passing variable from LogIn Page to LoggedIn page is another matter. How can i tell the HomePage that the user LoggedIn in the Tab LoginPage. (HomePage and LoginPage are two different tabs) thanks!

Comment: As I commented in one of your posts, on launching the app, you will have two possibilities 1. Not yet logged in 2. Already logged in. For both the possibilities you have to display a different page so you should evaluate the condition in any of the page and you will redirect to Home page or login page and pass in any variables you want to supply to home page or login page. If App comes to Home page it's known that you are already logged In and you don't need to check any condition. if you want to check again you can also run firebase auth 2nd time in home page constructor

Comment: Ah I see what you mean. becasue for me what I want is for the app to always go to Home page on start, whether logged in or not... and the homepage itself never changes. (LoginPage byitself automatically checks on run if the user is logged in and redirects correctly already) so my solution now is to implement the same checks in homepage as well? i thought checking the variable user in the LoginPage would have been a much better approach)

Comment: Thanks! Implementing the same check function in the homepage as well worked beautifully! :)