# Value of checkbox does not pass to the template page

Tags: ionic2

Assuming my driver has an id, how do I pass its value to the next page?

**html file**

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let driver of items; let i = index ">
            <ion-label>{{driver.name}}</ion-label>
            <ion-checkbox [(ngModel)]="driver[i]" item-right></ion-checkbox>
</ion-item>
```

[For example, I wanna check and names and assign to another driver, I want the names to appear on the input fields but it does not appear at all](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n7Vpv.jpg)

[Example of the value fo the checkbox does not appear at all](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZKOE.jpg)

**ts file**

```
initializeItems() {
        this.drivers =  [];

        this.driver.getDrivers((data)=>{
            console.log(data);

            for(let i in data.drivers){
                this.drivers.push({name: data.drivers[i].name, id: data.drivers[i].id})
            }
            this.items = this.drivers;
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with the below example. you can add a one more property to driver object to track the selection. check the working version [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-checkbox)

**home.html**

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Home</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>

  <ion-list>

  <ion-item  *ngFor="let ing of pizzaIng; let i = index">
    <ion-label>{{ing.name}}</ion-label>
    <ion-checkbox [(ngModel)]="ing.checked"  (ionChange)="updateIng()"></ion-checkbox>
  </ion-item>



</ion-list>

</ion-content>
```

**home.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
  pizzaIng : any;
  selectedIng : any=[];
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
    this.pizzaIng=[
      {name : "Pepperoni", checked : true},
      {name : "Sasuage", checked : true},
      {name : "Mushrooms", checked : true}
    ]
  }

  updateIng(){
    this.selectedIng=[];
    for(let ingr of this.pizzaIng){
      if(ingr.checked === true){
      this.selectedIng.push(ingr);
      }
    }
    console.log(this.selectedIng);
  }



}
```

Comment: selectedIng will have all the checked items. what else you want?

Comment: I want the value to appear on my 2nd page as shown in my picture tho but my label always show Not Assigned :(

Comment: if the second page is another component file use navParams to send value from one file to another file  this.navCtrl.push(this.aboutPage, {
            userData: selectedIng
        }); refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47190615/access-a-variable-from-another-component-ionic-cordova-angular/47194397#47194397